# C# equivalent of requests.post() function

Tags: python-requests

I'm converting some python scripts to its C# equivalent. When I run the following script (using requests module), the sever is happy and there is no issue with it:

```
auth_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
r = requests.post(api_url + '/v1/instances', headers=auth_header, json =params)
```

However, when I run the following C# equivalent code, the server returns "405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED":

```
HttpClient client  = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(api_url);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
          System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
          // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
          new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"application/json"));
          string jsonDumps = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
          var content = new StringContent(jsonDumps, Encoding.UTF8,@"application/json");
          var postResult = client.PostAsync(@"v1/pipelines", content).Result; // ERROR: 
             //StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'METHOD NOT ALLOWED'.
```

It is notable that there is no issue when I run the GET method:

```
var response = client.GetAsync(@"v1/pipelines").Result;
```

I do not have access to the sever code. I tried to use Fiddler (similar to wire shark) to see what the python code is sending to the server but using Fiddler causes the python script failed to work properly stating that SSLError: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED].

Comment: I think you're posting to two different endpoints - Python to /v1/instances and C# to /v1/pipelines. Try swapping them and seeing what happens.

Comment: Wow!!! I cannot believe I've made such a petty mistake. I wasted 3 days on that. It works now. Please put your comment as as answer.

Comment: We've all been there! :-) Answer has been posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a quick glance, the C# code looks correct. However, I think you're posting to two different endpoints: Python to /v1/instances and C# to /v1/pipelines. Try swapping them and seeing what happens.